How to use KeyboardInterrupt with other exceptions?
I'm trying to use KeyboardInterrupt along with other errors but it doesn't seem to be working. (I have pyautogui and time imported already.)
New to python btw.
while true
  try:
      x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('default.png')                                                 
      pyautogui.click(x, y)
      print (x, y)
      time.sleep(0.5)

  except ImageNotFoundException:
      print ("Nope nothing there. Try number:", tries)
      time.sleep(1)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print("Manual shutdown activated...")
      time.sleep(1)
      break;


Maybe it is obvious, but just in case this is what you are missing: KeyboardInterrupt will just trigger if you press ctrl+C on the terminal which is controlling your app - and not if the focused desktop application is anything else

I know, I selected it but it still gives me the keyboard interrupt error, not printing my words.

Is there supposed to be a loop around this code? You can't have break without a loop. And why do you have ; after it?

Forgot to add the loop part to this post. What what does SIGINT mean?

SIGINT is how the O.S. communicates the app that Keyboard interrupt was pressed. However, Python takes care of picking the O.S. SigInt and translate it into a KeyboardInterrupt exception which should work the way you are doing (but check my suggestion in the answer)  - for other languages one may have to register a handler for the OS interruption from scratch, and it is likely what @StasSimonov thought that in Python it is also needed: it is not.

But just in case you don´t get KeyboardInterrupt to work, you can try to handle SigInt explicitly - check the docs on the signal stdlib docs  - https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html and set a handler that would override Python's code which generate the KeyboardInterrupt exception.

Here is a complete example of what you have with some time exaggerations:
import time

while True:
    print('outside try')
    time.sleep(1)  # interrupting here won't be caught
    try:
        print('inside try')  # interrupting here will be caught (small window)
        with open('nonexistent.file') as f:  # This will go to FileNotFoundError
            pass
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('file not found')
        time.sleep(.5)  # interrupting here won't be caught
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    print('outside try')
    time.sleep(1)  # interrupting here won't be caught

print('exiting')

Wrap exactly the areas you expect to catch.  Put the KeyboardInterrupt try around the whole while loop, and the FileNotFoundError try around opening the file:
try:
    while True:
        try:
            with open('nonexistent.file') as f:
                pass
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('file not found')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('exiting')


KeyboardInterrupt will only get captured in this code if it takes place when the code inside the try: block is being executed - this is would be higly probable in the snippet presented here, as all the code does is rerun this block.
However, the while true in pseudo code style (working code would be while True:) suggest that this is just an attempt of a minimal reproducible example, which probably doesn't reproduce your actual code accuratelly.
All that said, create a try/except KeyboardInterrupt block around your (real) while True: block, not inside it - that is probably what is going wrong there.

I'm new to python what does around your real while True mean?

Just the loop you have in your actual running code - as this one you just typed as an example in the question to illustrate that there is a loop.

Wait @jsbueno It raised an error during the ImageNotFoundException error is that the problem?
